# How can I select only the points in a mixed geometry column in postgis postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql

```
        Table "public.eating_drinking"
 Column |          Type           | Modifiers 
--------+-------------------------+-----------
 osm_id | bigint                  | 
 way    | geometry(Geometry,4326) |
```

I'd like to do something like select * from eating_drinking where is_point(way)='t';

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from eating_drinking where ST_GeometryType(way)='ST_Point'
```